# How to Change the Database Source from within an application

Tags: xampp, php-7

I'm developing an app on xammp that allows you add multiple schools, and with each new school added, a new database is added. All that works fine.

The issue is in switching from database name to another database name in my db config. I have a form action "set_source" that triggers the setDBNAME action but get an uncaught error.

I tried the following code

```
    class dbConfig
    {
        public $hostname = 'localhost';   //hostname for db connection
        public $username = 'root';  // username for db connection
        public $password = 'password';  //password for db conection         
        public $dbname   = 'school1'; //this must be dynamically changeable
        public $mysqli;

        function setDBNAME($id)
        {
            $sql = "SELECT `school_name`, `subdomain`, `selected`, `url` FROM board.school WHERE school_id = $id AND selected = 'True'"; 
$data = $this->mysqli->execute_query($sql); //line triggering error
       if($data) {
  return new dbConfig(localhost, root, password, $data['url']);
       } 
       else {
  return null;
       }

    }

    }
```

But Got the following error

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute_query()
    on null in path\to\file\dbConfig.php:15 Stack trace: #0 path\to
    \file\myaccountController.php(50): dbConfig->setDBNAME('1') #1
    path\to\file\Controller11.php(29): myaccountController->set_source()
    #2 path\to\file\myaccount.php(20): Controller11->run() #3 {main}
    thrown in path\to\file\dbConfig.php on line 15
```

Any pointers and or solutions will be muchos gracias

Comment: You dont have a $mysqli var in your dbConfig?

Insert this below $dbname:
public $mysqli;

Comment: Thank you @Lars Hansen but the Fatal Error still persists. I run the SQL query in phpmyadmin and get a result. Why is it saying that it is NULL

Comment: In your code you have a $mysql and a $mysqli?

Comment: did you instanciate the $mysqli class somewhere? The code needs to know that $this->mysqli is a mysqli class. Personally I use PDO - much easier to work with and you can change db very easy.

Comment: Thank you @Lars Hansen. Not sure what you mean by instantiate but i have corrected the typo and still have the same issue. How do i instantiate it on this same page?

Comment: The error message says this: Call to a member function execute_query()
    on null. 

It is searching for a execute_query() (is that a homemade func/method?) in the $mysqli var. But $mysqli is NULL.

Comment: I tried extendiing the class like so

Comment: I tried extendiing the class like so class dbConfig extends Model which is where my execute_query is defined but i get the following error: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted. How do i make it access the mysqli model